# find a file and send some text to it

Tags: bash, xargs

I would like to find a file in folder `/opt` and send some text to it. I tried the following syntax:

```
sudo find /opt -name filename-*.conf | xargs -I '{}' echo "text_to_send" > '{}' \;
```

Unfortunately, after that I find the file named `{}` which contains the text. I tried using `'{}'` as well as `{}`,`"{}"`,`\{\}`, but in the command, but nothing seems to work correctly as a placeholder for the found filename. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo find /opt -name filename-*.conf -exec bash -c 'echo "text_to_send" > {}' \;
```

The `bash -c` is necessary in order to put the redirect `>` in quotes for `find -exec`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is technically ok if run in a console, but unfortunately, for some reason it didn't work for me in the context of provisioning used in a vagrant file. Vagrant complained about no attributes to -exec.

Answer (score 0):

I think `>` is interpreted in the current shell. The same applies to `*`, i.e. if you happen to have `filename-A.conf` (or worse: more matching files) in the current directory then shell globbing will break your command furhter. Also note: your `sudo` applies to `find` only, not to `xargs`.

Try this (with `sudo` if needed):

```
find /opt -name 'filename-*.conf' -print0 | xargs -r0 sh -c 'echo "text_to_send" | tee "$0" "$@"' > /dev/null
```

**Warning:** `tee` will overwrite files (like `>` does, so I guess this is what you want); use `tee -a` to append.

- `find -print0` and `xargs -0` work even with fancy filenames,
- `xargs -r` doesn't run if no file is found,
- `sh` handles the inner pipe,
- `$0" "$@"` passes all the filenames (postpended by `xargs`) to the command under `sh` in a safe way,
- `tee` handles one or multiple files found,
- the final redirection is to prevent `text_to_send` from appearing in your terminal.

Comment: This solution works even in a vagrant file, but there were some problems with `text_to_send` containing `" "`, which were erased after all. So eventually I had to resort to other solution, but this one gave me a good insight anyway, so thank you.